# Sync issue in Linux C reading and writing to a file concurrently

Tags: c, linux, file, synchronization, locking

I'm trying to test possible problems for reading from and writing to same files concurrently on an embedded device which has embedded Linux on it.

I have two processes: Writer and Reader. As the names suggest, the Writer constantly writes 1 of 3 const strings to 10 files one-by-one and at the same time the Reader reads the same files and compares the outputs to be sure they are correct. In order to overcome synchronization issues, I thought I could use mandatory file locking mechanism.

**Note:** Reader process is actually a placeholder for an user application which will read the files in a similar fashion. Since it will not be in my control, advisory file locking will not be applicable.

I have mounted a tmpfs with mandatory file locking enabled.

```
mount -t tmpfs -o mand,size=1m tmpfs /tmp2
```

The Writer creates 10 files with mandatory file locking enabled. And in each iteration one of the three strings below is written to files.

```
const char* s1 = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
const char* s2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char* s3 = "************************************************************************";
```

The Reader reads these files one-by-one and reports if there is a mismatch. And it occasionally (roughly once in every 1000 iterations, see the codes below) reads strings like:

```
"************************************************************************62862089986280348253421170679"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz********************"
```

This is exactly the problem I was expecting to encounter. The smaller strings are written on top of the bigger ones and the remaining characters are not deleted.

I tried to use `fsync(fn)` after writing to file, but it did not work. It should not be needed anyway, since this is a tmpfs.

What is the reason for this and what can I do to avoid this?

Here are the codes for the Writer and the Reader:

**The Writer**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

const char* s1 = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
const char* s2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char* s3 = "************************************************************************";

int main()
{
    // create /tmp2/test directory
    if (mkdir("/tmp2/test", 0777) == -1) {
        if (errno != EEXIST) {
            perror("mkdir");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // create 10 input files input0, input1, ..., input9
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char path[50] = "/tmp2/test/input";
        sprintf(path + 16, "%d", i);
        FILE* fp = fopen(path, "w");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create file %s\n", path);
            perror("create: ");
            return -1;
        }
        chmod(path, 02644); //mandatory file locking enabled
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // flock structure
    struct flock fl;
    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 0;
    fl.l_pid = 0;

    // loop
    for(int step = 0; ; step++) {
        usleep(50000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            char path[50] = "/tmp2/test/input";
            sprintf(path + 16, "%d", i);

            FILE* fp = fopen(path, "w+");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", path);
                perror("fopen: ");
                return -1;
            }
            int fd = fileno(fp);

            // place a write lock
            fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
            if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
                perror("lock: ");
                return -1;
            }

            // write 1 of 3 strings
            if (step % 3 == 0) {
                write(fd, s1, strlen(s1));
            } else if (step % 3 == 1) {
                write(fd, s2, strlen(s2));
            } else {
                write(fd, s3, strlen(s3));
            }
            //fsync(fd);    // fsync should not be needed since this is a tmpfs

            // unlock
            fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
            if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
                perror("lock: ");
                return -1;
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The Reader:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

const char* s1 = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
const char* s2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char* s3 = "************************************************************************";

int main()
{
    // counters for errors
    int err_ctr = 0;
    int read_err_ctr = 0;

    // loop
    for(int step = 0; ; step++) {
        usleep(50000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            char path[50] = "/tmp2/test/input";
            sprintf(path + 16, "%d", i);
            FILE* fp = fopen(path, "r");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", path);
                perror("read: ");
                return -1;
            }

            // read the file
            char reading[150];
            if (fgets(reading, 150, fp) == NULL) {
                fclose(fp);
                read_err_ctr++;
                printf("Step = %d; ReadError = %d; from %s\n", step, read_err_ctr, path);
                continue;
            }
            fclose(fp);

            // continue if the string matches
            if (strcmp(reading, s1) == 0) {
                continue;
            } else if (strcmp(reading, s2) == 0) {
                continue;
            } else if (strcmp(reading, s3) == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // print error
            err_ctr++;
            printf("Step = %d; Error = %d; I've read %s from %s\n", step, err_ctr, reading, path);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your approach (mandatory locking) is not going to work reliably in Linux. Do you know if the reader process keeps the file open, or if it opens the file every time it reads it? You can check by running it under `strace`. If it does open it every time, the solution is simple (temporary file in same directory or filesystem, and atomic replace via `link()`). Otherwise, you need workarounds.

Comment: Are you running multiple writer processes simultaneously?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Just one writer and one reader.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The files will be opened and closed every time. I'll try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @Durmus With just a single writer process, you should not be getting more than one of your three output strings written to any one file.  The `fopen(path, "w+");` call should truncate the file when it's opened, and you only write one of the three strings to the file in each loop.  As far as I can tell, the posted code can't create the data you're seeing in your output files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, but it does. I've tried truncating explicitly as well with truncate call, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Durmus Try different filesystems, such as XFS and/or ext4.  Because that looks like a filesystem and/or page cache problem.  When you open a file that contains "ABCDEFGH", truncate the file to zero bytes, then write "1234" to the file, there should be no way any reader ever reads "1234EFGH", locking or not.  You can also try running both your processes under `strace` to see what system calls are actually being made, and especially the actual bytes the reader process gets from the kernel.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Going from your example, this occurs when the opposite happens. Namely, if the file contains "1234" and Reader opens it to read and then right at this point Writer opens the file and writes "ABCDEFGH" to it. Then somehow Reader continues to read the remaining characters and hence "1234EFGH". Indeed, strace shows two read calls from Reader process.

Comment: @Durmus Well, that's surprising. Your `fgets()` implementation is not atomic. It gets to the end of the file, and tries to get more data - and sometimes finds some. How much do you know about your intended reader process?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The user application will periodically be checking the contents of the files, while in the background my Writer process updates the contents. I also found out that in the Writer process, if I use `fprintf()` instead of `write()` command, I do not observe this behavior. The reader process occasionally gets  `NULL` reads, but no mixed strings.